# MacOS slowed down after VsCode update

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

TLDR; I updated my Vscode yesterday ([c3511e6](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5)) and starting to notice my machine slowing down ever since. I want to know if maybe someone is experiencing the same or if there's another possible reason for this.

**Please see below for more info:**

1. **All** the updates on my machine is done manually (automatic updates are turned off).
2. I'm using Macbook Pro Intel 2020.
3. Here's the "About" section of my Vscode.

[image]

4. I already re-started twice since the update.
5. Here's my Macbook Specs.

[image]

6. Here's my Activity Monitor screenshot taken today:
   [image]
7. Checked vscode's github repo and found [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/150445) but it's Terminal related so I'm not sure if this is relevant but we're using the same version and machine.

Comment: Just a suggestion; try to update to the latest version of Monterey which is `12.4` and see the result!!
[see this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212585)

Comment: By design, APFS is really slow on HD the more files you have in it, and even after you delete them, the metadata is still going to be scattered all over the place. https://bombich.com/blog/2019/09/12/analysis-apfs-enumeration-performance-on-rotational-hard-drives It's possible the recent update adds enough files to reach the threshold.

Comment: Typically the more things installed, the slower your machine becomes...

Answer (score 0):

Team member here. Can you please file an issue using `Help: Report Issue` and pick `Performance Issue`. It will include the right diagnostic data to follow up. Alternatively you can also open the DevTools (via command) and record a performance trace (can be saved and attached to an issue).

Answer (score 0):

Since issues started appearing when I manage to add R extension and use Markdown as .ipynb on vscode. So I gave up on R extension, which seems like helped